# Python: Pulling a URL request from Pancakeswap API

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I made a request to Pancake swap API, I only need the first 6 digits of the price in Bold letter below. The final goal is to get a notification when price goes below or above X price.

this what I get from the API:

{"updated_at":1644088600598,"data":{"name":"SugarBounce","symbol":"TIP","price":"**0.3895**97450332099015858871009432","price_BNB":"0.0009419388066193731353156275432376"}}

I'm using BeautifulSoup and request library.

```
url = 'https://api.pancakeswap.info/api/v2/tokens/0x40f906e19b14100d5247686e08053c4873c66192'
data = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.content, 'html.parser')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following to get the first 6 digits of the price

The price is sent as a string therefore you can do some list slicing to get the digits that you would like.

```
import requests
import json
url = 'https://api.pancakeswap.info/api/v2/tokens/0x40f906e19b14100d5247686e08053c4873c66192'
data = requests.get(url).json()

price = float(data['data']['price'][:6]) # to get the first 6 digits of the price
```

Though the price is a float and would probably just be better off comparing the previous price to this new price from the API call.

Answer (score 0):

let's call the dictionary you are getting from the API `result`. Now you can obtain the price as follows:

```py
price_str = result['price']
firstdigits = price_str[:6]
```

The digits will be in string format. If you need a float just use

```py
digits = float(firstdigits)
```

Comment: The result from the requests needs to be converted into some form of dictionary before you can access its elements. The dictionary is also set up where the price is inside of dictionary inside the response dictionary.